# How to fill in a datetime-local field with capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I am using Cocoon to add records. IDs look like `workshop_instance_sessions_attributes_1477654140_start_time` . At the moment I am traversing the DOM and grabbing the dynamically generated IDs (this works fine) so I can use them to reference the input to fill in. I have tried many things (many that work in console) and still cannot seem to get the spec to work. Below are a selection of things I've tried (`first` is the variable which holds the id and `@time` is basically Time.now that increments as a block executes).

Works in console:

`page.evaluate_script("document.getElementById('#{first}').value = '#{@time.strftime('%Y-%m-%eT%H:%M')}'")`

`page.evaluate_script("$('##{first}').val('#{@time.strftime("%Y-%m-%eT%H:%M")}')")`

Doesn't work in console:

`fill_in first, with: @time.strftime("%Y-%m-%eT%H:%M")`

`find("##{first}").set(@time.strftime("%Y-%m-%eT%H:%M"))`

These are all already within a within block (a common issue I run into) that I know is working correct as the first variable is being correctly set.

As reference my html looks like this:

`<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="workshop_instance[sessions_attributes][1477655024][start_time]" id="workshop_instance_sessions_attributes_1477655024_start_time">`

Any pointers on how to get this spec to work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you experiment with different different datetime formats and using `select` instead of `fill_in`?

Comment: Yes and yes. I have this working with just date field. It seems to be an issue with the date and time together.

Comment: I suggest you [open a PR](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). It would be sad if Capybara doesn't support `datetime-local` ATM, but it definitely is a possibility.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Capybara release notes [here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#changed-4):

> Selenium driver supports Date/Time when filling in date/time/datetime-local inputs

So to answer your question:

```
fill_in first, with: Time.new(2018, 01, 02, 12)
```

Comment: for some reason this doesn't trigger React's `onChange`

Answer (score 7):

This is going to vary based on driver/browser used.  Assuming you're using selenium-webdriver with chrome you need to set the keys that would be hit to enter in the control so to set december 13th 2000 @ 3:15 PM you would need to do

```
fill_in first, with: "12132000\t0315p"
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. I'm not sure what capybara "sees" when it evaluates a page and then selects fields, but in almost every browser a datetime field is rendered as two separate fields and then combined by the DOM when submitted. That would explain why the javascript `.val()` setting works, but manually doing it (as capybara attempts) through filling in doesn't.

Comment: this works with React's `onChange`

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the simple solution combined with a hack to trigger the `onChange` of React:

```rb
fill_in "Date and hour", with: 1.day.from_now
# HACK: triggers onChange
find("input[type=datetime-local]").send_keys(:arrow_up)
```

It changes the date though

Comment: To not change the date, one can `find("input[type=datetime-local]").send_keys(:arrow_up, :arrow_down)`

Comment: @morgoth nice, didn't think of it!

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, it also seem to work with the simple ISO format:

```rb
fill_in first, with: "2017-08-02T15:27"
```

---

Not related to the choosen input format but I had a related problem with validation though, because when changing the value my browser (chrome) was expecting a value with the **same number of second as the previous time**. To fix this I had to set the [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#step) attribute to "1" ("any" probably works too):

```rb
datetime_field(:created_at, step: 1)
```

Step defaults to 60, meaning the time must be rounded up or down to the nearest 60 seconds (1 minute). This looked ok in my case because I didn't need second precision. But the problem is if you load the form with a value containing seconds (what `datetime_field` does by default), then when changing it you must keep the same number of seconds or you get a validation error. So for example if you had "15:12:24" initially, you can change it to "16:42:24" but not to "16:42:00". (that would mean in your test reading the seconds value from existing attribute to inject it into the newly generated time, not very practical and readable). Good to know :)