# How to fill in a datetime field with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I found this similar question [How to fill in a datetime-local field with capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304521/how-to-fill-in-a-datetime-local-field-with-capybara?rq=1), and the only answer in this thread is not working. So I decided to open this question. It seems like there's no documentation or tutorial about this. Have any solution? It will be a great help!

Comment: With which driver and browser

Comment: I use selenium and chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys different browsers accept for setting a datetime input field are diffrent, however if you're using selenium with chrome and you are actually attempting to fill in a visible `<input type="datetime-local">` element, as your question states, then the answer in the question your linked to should work -  Here is a gist that shows it working - https://gist.github.com/twalpole/a541746b354afde8e82fa89a35a9b2da

The important part in that answer is the format of the string you send since it needs to match the keys the browser is expecting for setting that input (`to_json` doesn't match that format)

Therefore, in your case of wanting to set `DateTime.current` it should be something along the lines of

```
fill_in 'id/name/label of input', with: DateTime.current.strftime("%m%d%Y\t%I%M%P")
```

If that doesn't work for you then most likely you're not actually attempting to fill a visible `<input type="datetime-local">` field (maybe you're using some kind of JS widget that replaces/hides the input???) and you'll need to specify the exact HTML you are trying to fill in your question.

Comment: Thanks your solution works! I just want to know why does capybara do not allow `to_json` format? I use this format in my javascript codes

Comment: @gilbertlcsndle It's not that capybara doesn't allow it - it's that Chrome doesn't expect the keys in that order. `to_json` produces a string like "\"2018-03-09T11:04:59.243+00:00\"" - if you manually click into the datetime-local input and start typing those keys you'll see that Chrome  doesn't accept them.

Comment: It would be nice if capybara has a method for filling in datetime fields.

Comment: @gilbertlcsndle Very few people actually use plain datetime fields on their sites - most use  some JS widget to allow consistent styling and behavior across different browsers which means any such method wouldn't be used very often, however PRs to the Capybara project are always considered

Comment: I think the missing piece for me was the `strftime` you added, including the tab (`\t`). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand, you need to fill in a **string** representation of the datetime format

examples of such dates are

1990-12-31T23:59:60Z

or

1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00

so something like

```
fill_in datetimeinput, with: "1990-12-31T23:59:60Z"
```

should work (hope so!)

Comment: Your solution might work, I'll try it later. But I want to use `Datetime.current` for its value, I think it's more cleaner? I tried this `DateTime.current.to_json`, but when I run the specs, it says it is an invalid format.